# System.out.println() behavior on surrogate pair char[]

Tags: java, char, utf-16, println

When I execute the code:

```
char[] c1 = {'a','b'};
char[] c2 = Character.toChars(0x10437);
System.out.println(c1);
System.out.println(c2);
```

I get:

```
ab
```

By reading the documentation of `Character.toChars`, I get that `c2` is a char array of size 2, which is the surrogate pair that represents `0x10437` in UTF-16.

What I don't understand is that `c1` and `c2` are both char arrays of length 2, then how does `println` know that `c1` represents 2 characters ('a' and 'b') while `c2` represents only 1 character ? Why `println` doesn't recognize `c2` as two characters?

Comment: Probably you have to change the `PrintStream` encoding. Otherwise it translates c2 back to unicode. That's just a guess, anyway, I'm not sure

Comment: By the way, see that same text analyzed using code point integer numbers, demonstrated  in code running at [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/68IWqa). `ab` ➔ `[97, 98, 66615]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [javadoc for `Character.tochars(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toChars(int)) states (with my emphasis added):

> Converts the specified character (Unicode code point) to its UTF-16
> representation stored in a char array. If the specified code point is
> a BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane or Plane 0) value, the resulting char
> array has the same value as codePoint. **If the specified code point is
> a supplementary code point, the resulting char array has the
> corresponding surrogate pair.**

So, as you point out, your statement `char[] c2 = Character.toChars(0x10437);` causes the high-surrogate of that code point to be placed in `c2[0]`, and the low-surrogate of the code point to be placed in `c2[1]`;

You can display the hex values of that surrogate pair:

```
System.out.printf("High: 0x%X%n", (int)c2[0]);
System.out.printf("Low:  0x%X%n", (int)c2[1]);
```

This is the output from that code:

```
High = 0xD801
Low = 0xDC37
```

Now `println()` "knows" to treat those two array elements as a surrogate pair for rendering a single character because surrogate values are in specific ranges:

- The range U+D800 to U+DBFF is exclusively for high surrogates.
- The range U+DC00 to U+DFFF is exclusively for low surrogates.

(Somewhat confusingly, high surrogate values are lower than low surrogate values.) See section [**3.8 Surrogates** of the Unicode Standard](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode14.0.0/UnicodeStandard-14.0.pdf) for the rules, but this is the crucial point: *"Isolated surrogate code units have no interpretation on their own"*. So when `println()` encounters the value 0xD801 it knows that it can only be a high surrogate (and nothing else), and that it must be followed by a low surrogate in the range U+DC00 to U+DFFF. It can then construct a code point from that surrogate pair, and prints the character represented by that code point.

A lot of confusion arises from the multiple meanings of the word *"character"* in Java, Unicode and plain English. Generally we think of a one-to-one mapping between some digital character value (i.e. code point) and its visual representation, so the Unicode character U+0077 represents the visual character *`w`*, and the Java character (`char`) 'w'. But in your example, the surrogate pair U+D801 and 0xDC37 do not represent individual characters at all, and they are only meaningful when combined together to form the code point (character) x10437, which is represented by the visual character .